# Centos 7 - Autenticação de proxy sem salvar senha

Tags: linux, centos, proxy

Existe alguma forma de configurar o proxy no arquivo "/etc/yum.conf" sem que deixe a senha salva neste arquivo? Algo do tipo, passar a senha por parâmetro?

Hoje fica a senha escrita no arquivo da seguinte maneira:

```
# HABILITAR PROXY CENTOS 7:
# The proxy server - proxy server:port number
proxy=http://10.10.10.10:3128
# The account details for yum connections
proxy_username=dominio\usuario
proxy_password=123456
```

A ideia é que a senha não fique salva, evitando assim uma possível quebra de segurança em caso de uso.

Obrigado.

Comment: Como vc executa esse proxy? via terminal?

Comment: Então, pra utiizar a maquina na rede eu salvo essas informações no arquivo "/etc/yum.conf"...

Comment: Mas quem paga essa info?

Answer (score 1):

Considere simplesmente definir as permissões do `yum.conf` como `0600` e sempre executar o `yum` como root. Assim só quem conhecer a senha de root poderá ler a senha do proxy na configuração.

Dito isso, em shell script você pode pedir a senha para o usuário e executar o `yum` num contexto que contenha essa variável de ambiente. Assim a informação confidencial fica em memória apenas durante a execução do processo:

```
#!/bin/bash
# yum.pedesenha.sh
read -sp 'Informe o endereço do proxy: ' endereco;
read -sp 'Informe o usuário do proxy: ' usuario;
read -sp 'Informe a senha do proxy: ' senha;
proxy=$endereco proxy_username=$usuario proxy_password=$senha yum "$@";
```

Execute passando parâmetros como um `yum` comum:

```
$ ./yum.pedesenha.sh check-update
```

Claro, talvez você só não goste da ideia de deixar a senha no arquivo de configuração, mas deixar endereço e usuário lhe seja tranquilo. Simplesmente remova as linhas de `read` e as atribuições para as variáveis de ambiente na última linha para os parâmetros que continuam sendo definidos no `yum.conf`.